# In C# WinForm app, How to paint/draw child form close button

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-styles

How to paint/draw a child form's close button (not MDI Form close button).

[image]

MDI form's close button cand be draw by  **System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement.Window.CloseButton.Normal** but how to draw **child form's close button** as seen in the picture.

I have got a thing but it is not same as in image displayed. System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement.Window.MdiCloseButton.Normal

MdiCloseButton will provide the same thing.

Comment: What goal are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i want to draw icon like in brown circle, an 'X' sign.

Comment: That icon is by default there for all mdi-child forms then why you need to draw it?

Comment: i want to draw it explicitly on my customize control. Not on form

Comment: It is not drawn by a visual style renderer.  Looks like an Office custom style.  Painting an x like that is otherwise simple.

Comment: then, how can i draw this ?